# How do you say "You have gotten better at X"?

Tags: usage, adjectives, phrase-requests, na-adjectives

I was just reminded on another site that "being good at something" is expressed as `[上手]{じょうず}/[上手]{うま}い`, not `いい`. How do you tell someone they "have gotten better at something"? `Xさん, 料理することがもっと上手いですね。` would be my thought. Is that right? Would that be the way a native would say it? Is that even how a textbook would word it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `なる` (to become) to indicate change, as follows:

> うまくなる (い-adjective, い->く)
>   上手になる (な-adjective + に)

These both mean "to become good/skilled".

Then for "to become more skilled" you can use もっと, さらに or 前より:

> もっと上手になる to become better
>   さらに上手になる to become even better
>   前より上手になる to become better than before

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way of saying "you've gotten better" is `上手になりました`. A lot of the time you hear `ね` after that :)

Answer (score 3):

- `うまい` can be written with the same kanji as `[上]{じょう}[手]{ず}`: `[上手]{うま}い`.
- As you have in your English phrase, the natural way to say it in Japanese is to use "have gotten" or "become", which is `なる` in Japanese, as ジョン answers.
- Alternatively, it is possible to stick with `だ` or `です` as in your answer using `もっと`, but in that case, the standard for comparison is not clear enough without explicit mentioning. It can be taken that you are comparing with someone else. You need to add a phrase like `前より` or `以前より` to indicate that the comparison is along time. Then, you do not necessarily need `もっと` as comparison would be expressed by such phrase.
- But more importantly, `こと` cannot be used in this combination.

> 料理が(前より(もっと)) {上手だ/上手い/上手になった/上手くなった}
>   　料理するのが(前より(もっと)) {上手だ/上手い/上手になった/上手くなった}
>   * 料理することが(前より(もっと)) {上手だ/上手い/上手になった/上手くなった}

If you are using `得意` "be good at", then using `こと` is not as bad.

> 料理が得意だ
>   料理するのが得意だ　
>   料理することが得意だ

Comment: What's the difference between `no` and `koto`? From what I understand, they serve the same function. Do they not?

Comment: No they are different. I was expecting someone will ask this, and finally, you asked. It could be an independent question.

Comment: Well I will ask independently then :)